# XML parsing using fast_iter clearing data before done processing

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

Im using Liza Daly's fast_iter which has the structure of:

```
def fast_iter(context, args=[], kwargs={}):
    """
    Deletes elements as the tree is travsersed to prevent the full tree from building and save memory
    Author: Liza Daly, IBM
    """
    for event, elem in context:
        if elem.tag == 'target':
            func(elem, *args, **kwargs)
            
            elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]
    del context
    return save
```

However, Ive noticed when i create my context as

```
context = etree.iterparse(path, events=('end',))
```

The data within the elem gets deleted before my function can even process it. For clarity, I am using fully synchronous code.

If I set my context as

```
context = etree.iterparse(path, events=('end',), tag='target')
```

It works correctly, however I know its not doing the full memory conservation that fast_iter is intended to provide.

Is there any reason to even use this when compared to `xml.dom.pulldom`, a SAX parser which creates no tree? It seems like `fast_iter` attempts to replicate this staying within `lxml`.

Does anyone have ideas on what im doing wrong? TIA

Comment: Bump for visibility

Comment: If you set `tag='target'`, your code works and you get the data you want? What is meant by "not doing the full memory conservation"? Perhaps illustrate with some samples in what way data you need is cleared before you can access it and in what way your use of `tag='target'` does not give you the wanted behaviour.

Comment: I read that when you do tag='target' within iterparse, it will still develop the full tree despite clearing which is the antithesis of `fast_iter`

Comment: Can you provide minimal samples that demonstrate/allow others to reproduce that your code deletes data before the function can process it? Are there any nested `target` elements? Siblings?

Comment: I don't think the full tree is developed and preserved if you clear, rather, if you use `tag='foo'`, and `element.clear()`, and keep `context.root`, you get a root containing the a tree with ancestors of `foo` elements and the empty/cleared `foo` elements. Assuming the bulk of the data was the content of each `foo` that way the memory footprint should be much lower than having stored the full tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can see where your approach might delete data you want to access before the code to access it is called, let's assume you have e.g.

```
<target>
  <foo>test</foo>
  <bar>test</bar>
</target>
```

elements in your XML, then each time an end element tag is found your code

```
for event, elem in context:
    if elem.tag == 'target':
        func(elem, *args, **kwargs)
        
        elem.clear()
    while elem.getprevious() is not None:
        del elem.getparent()[0]
```

is run, meaning it encounters the `foo` end element tag, then the `bar` end element tag where the while loop deletes the `foo` sibling element and then the `target` end element tag is encountered and I assume your function looks for both the `foo` and the `bar` element data but the `foo` element has been deleted.

So somehow your code has to take the structure (you probably know) into account and don't do that while loop for children/descendants of your `target` element.